# A table with infinite rows?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a table posts:

```
      Column       |           Type           |                     Modifiers                      
-------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 body              | text                     | not null
 from              | character varying(2000)  | not null
 date              | timestamp with time zone | not null
```

and I'd like to count how many rows a user has in one day, one row for every day in a given month.

In oracle I would "generate" a table with as many days the current month has, and then join the "date" column with the "generated" date.

Something like

```
> select *
  2    from (select sysdate + level l from dual connect by level < 10)
  3  /

         L
----------
2013-06-07
2013-06-08
2013-06-09
2013-06-10
2013-06-11
2013-06-12
2013-06-13
2013-06-14
2013-06-15

9 rows selected.
```

Is there something similar in postgres?

Comment: You're probably looking for [`generate_series`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://diethardsteiner.blogspot.com/2012/03/postgresql-auto-generating-sample.html

I found this with just one google hit. U might try using it.

Incase the author removes or web page gets wiped out.

```
WITH date_series AS (
SELECT
   DATE(GENERATE_SERIES(DATE '2012-01-01', DATE '2012-01-10','1 day')) AS generateddate
)
SELECT 
      generateddate 
    , EXTRACT(DAY FROM generateddate) AS day
    , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM generateddate) AS month
    , EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM generateddate) AS quarter
    , EXTRACT(YEAR FROM generateddate) AS year
 FROM 
     date_series;
```

Comment: Thank you, you are awesome. I had no idea what to search for. "infinite table postgres" was obviously wrong.

Comment: You are welcome. I used the above trick in Oracle for a long time. And different tricks for the same functionality in older versions of Oracle.

Comment: Better not to use the word `date` as a column name, just because that's a bit confusing. `generate_series` over `date` and `interval` is certainly the way to go here.